# Delegates vs Action, Func in C#

Tags: c#, delegates

This might seem a silly question, but it's just for curiosity's sake.

We have two particular already-defined delegates in C#:

- [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx)
- [`Func<T, TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)

Action encapsulates **any** "void" method that takes 0 or more parameters.
Func encapsulates **any** method that returns a specific value type and takes 0 or more parameters.

My question is: in which cases it is recommended to define a custom delegate?
Why would you need to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Delegates were there before Func and Action and in many ways they serve as backward compatibility devices. However, there are instances when you can't get around but create your delegate.

Comment: Watch this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8o0O-vBS8W0 Might be useful.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

None of the `Func` or `Action` types allow `out` or `ref` parameters, so you'll have to define your own delegates if you need to use those e.g.:

```
public delegate bool TryParse<T>(string s, out T value);
```

Comment: Yep that's pretty logic. I don't know if that was yuor intention, but you just made me realize that Action and Func don't allow type parameters, either.<br/>
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have two return types in your delegate. I think you meant: public delegate **bool** TryParse<T>(string s, out T value); I wish I could edit it, but the 6 character rule still applies.

Comment: @user886079 - Yes I meant `bool`, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In thousand cases you'll need to refer/point to a function (hence a delegate, if actual implementation of the function will vary at run time, except the signature) that doesn't match either of the given delegates. Say

Public delegate T MyDel(T t, U u, V v);

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks man!